# Accounts.ui.config: Can't set `passwordSignupFields` more than once

Tags: meteor-accounts

In one of my react components, I have this

```
<a href={'/application/' + username +'/' +appid}>My Application</a>
```

When I click on that link, I get the javascript error `Accounts.ui.config: Can't set 'passwordSignupFields' more than once`.

However, when I go to the directly to the url `http://192.168.0.110:3000/application/john/X93ajdsfj` by pasting the url into the browser address bar, then the page loads without errors.  I only get an error when I load the page by click on the anchor tag.

I suspect that when I click on the link, I'm probably not doing a full HTTP page reload, and only parts are reloaded, and this javascript found in my `myproject.jsx` gets fired again:

```
  // This code is executed on the client only
  Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
```

I am completely new to meteor.  What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code out of the React component and into the main .jsx file of the meteor project and wrapped it with a Meteor.isClient if statement like so:

```
if(Meteor.isClient)
{
  // This code is executed on the client only
  Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
}
```